# Unable to connect to websocket

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat, websocket, jetty

I am facing an issue in connecting to websocket. For a simple test i opened this url http://www.websocket.org/echo.html and clicked connect. I am getting error undefined. 
Browser using chrome. I also tested in IE and firefox still the problem is same.

Can any one please help me whats wrong with my laptop. Till yesterday i was able to make websocket connect successfully but after my windows 10 updates now i am unable to make connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sweat. ws://echo.websocket.org is down.

Comment: yeah i tested with other websocket and its working fine.